# extra characters (newline/spaces) seen when accessing html element via jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to access `li` elements within `ul` . I am novice jquery user and I believe I am making some mistake because which I am seeing extra characters
( newline/space) when I try to print the value of `li` element.

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

```js
$(function () {
var a=$('ul.nav').find('li#tab2').text();
alert(a + '|next_text|');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
        <li id='tab1'><a href="?call=tab1">tab1</a>
        </li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li id='tab2'><a href="?call=tab2">tab2</a>
        </li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li id='tab3'><a href="?call=tab3">tab3</a>
        </li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li id='tab4'><a href="?call=tab4">tab4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In documentation I found

Due to variations in the HTML parsers in different browsers, the text returned may vary in newlines and other white space.
You see http://api.jquery.com/text/

You can use

```
$.trim($('ul.nav').find('li#tab2').text());
```